# CSV file gets lost between Python function calls

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, nonetype

I'm writing a script where I plot a pandas data frame. I first preprocess data in one file in a particular Python module. Then I import that function from the module. When I call the function in my new Python file, it thinks the data frame is a None type object whereas in the original function it prints the data frame correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from Preprocessing import sample_difference as sd

files = [
    'PickUpPhoneAccelerometer1.csv',
    'PickUpPhoneAccelerometer2.csv',
    'PickUpPhoneAccelerometer3.csv',
    'Wave1Accelerometer.csv',
    'Wave2Accelerometer.csv',
    'Wave3Accelerometer.csv'
]


def segment_energy(data, th):
    print data
    mag = np.array([np.linalg.norm(data['x']), np.linalg.norm(data['y']), np.linalg.norm(data['z'])])
```

Running this, data is `None`.

Here's the other Python file `sample_difference`

```
 def sample_difference(filename):
     df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')
     df.assign(dx=df.x.diff(), dy=df.y.diff(), dz=df.z.diff())
     print df
```

This prints out the data frame correctly. The error when I run the final script is:

```
line 17, in segment_energy
mag = np.array([np.linalg.norm(data['x']), np.linalg.norm(data['y']), np.linalg.norm(data['z'])])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm calling `segment_energy` as so in that same file:

```
for f in files:
    with open(os.path.join("/Users", "myname", "PycharmProjects", "sensorLogProject", "Data", f), 'rU') as my_file:
        segment_energy(sd.sample_difference(my_file), 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to call `sample_difference` function with a filename instead of the file object that is:

```
for f in files:
    filename = os.path.join("/Users", "myname", "PycharmProjects", "sensorLogProject", "Data", f)
    segment_energy(sd.sample_difference(filename), 2)
```

second, `sample_difference` function should be returning the dataframe instead of printing:

```
def sample_difference(filename):
     df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')
     df.assign(dx=df.x.diff(), dy=df.y.diff(), dz=df.z.diff())
     return df
```

Comment: The second change solved the error but the first change caused more errors. It probably has to do with how I'm accessing the files, but I'll keep it the same way. Thanks!